# How can I identify acceptor and donor atoms using BioPython?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, protein-database

I know how to traverse through structures, models, chains, residues, and atoms in a protein chain using BioPython ([which is very easy](http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#sec193)).

How can I identify donor and acceptor atoms in a chain by traversing?

Comment: does your model (is it  a PDB ?? ) has Hydrogens ? see here https://www.niist.res.in/chsuresh/HBPredict.html : Criteria for identifying Hydrogen Bonds, if you have H use all the criteria if not just the distance between donor and acceptor

Comment: if talking about SS (The secondary structure is formed by hydrogen bonds between carbonyl and amino groups that make up the polypeptide backbone and causes the molecule to either bend and fold or spiral around.. copied from google) just select either all O (acceptor from carbonil) or all N (donor amino) ande check the distance between all the corresponding pair (O1 vs all N, N1 - vs all O) to get the list of the putative donor/acceptor pairs. @Matteo Ferla am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

well gues Matteo is busy, so my attempt here is trying to use

> donor-acceptor distance and
> donor-acceptor-acceptor antecedent angle ( ^H)

from https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2665928X20300246 :
Peptide bond planarity constrains hydrogen bond geometry and influences secondary structure conformations

not sure the code is right, especially the H angle calculation, it's  probably not the fastest way too but nevertheless:

using as input .pdb file `16pk.pdb` from https://www.rcsb.org/structure/16PK

and my code copied from [How can I get a list of neighboring Hydrogen atoms of an alpha-carbon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69676943/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-neighboring-hydrogen-atoms-of-an-alpha-carbon/69815509#69815509):

```
import numpy as np

from Bio.PDB import Chain, Atom, NeighborSearch, PDBParser, Selection

def Hangle(ac: "C atom.coord" ,bc : " O atom.coord" ,cc: "N atom.coord") -> "H_angle" :
    """
    https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2665928X20300246
    
    Peptide bond planarity constrains hydrogen bond geometry and influences secondary structure conformations
    
    and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35176451/python-code-to-calculate-angle-between-three-point-using-their-3d-coordinates

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : "C atom.coord"
        DESCRIPTION.
    b : " O atom.coord"
        DESCRIPTION.
    c : "N atom.coord"
        DESCRIPTION.

    Returns
    -------
    TYPE
        DESCRIPTION.

    """
    a = np.array(ac)
    b = np.array(bc)
    c = np.array(cc)
    
    ba = a - b
    bc = c - b
    
    cosine_angle = np.dot(ba, bc) / (np.linalg.norm(ba) * np.linalg.norm(bc))
    angle = np.arccos(cosine_angle)
    
    return np.degrees(angle)




def get_putative_acceptors_list(n_donor_atom: Atom.Atom, po):
    ns = NeighborSearch(po)
    return [h for h in ns.search( n_donor_atom.get_coord(), 3.3, 'A') if h.element == 'O']



p = PDBParser()
structure = p.get_structure('16pk', '16pk.pdb')

n_donor_list = [atom for atom in structure.get_atoms() if atom.name == "N"]
    
    
po = Selection.unfold_entities(structure, 'A')

acceptor_list = []

water = 0
  
for n in range(len(n_donor_list)):
    
    o = get_putative_acceptors_list(n_donor_list[n], po)
    
    for i in o:
        if  i.get_parent().resname == 'HOH':
            water +=1
            # print('water', water)
            continue
        
        if i.name != 'O':
            # print(type(i))
            # # print(dir(i.get_parent()))
            # print(i, i.get_parent().resname, i.get_parent().id[1])
            continue
        else:
            if i.get_parent().id[1] != n_donor_list[n].get_parent().id[1]-1:
                 if i.get_parent().id[1] != n_donor_list[n].get_parent().id[1]:
                     
                     # if i.get_parent().id[1] == n_donor_list[n].get_parent().id[1]-3: #catches alpha elics ???
                
                         dist = np.linalg.norm(n_donor_list[n].coord - i.coord)
                         
                         h_angle = Hangle(i.get_parent()['C'].coord, i.coord,  n_donor_list[n].coord  )
                         
                         if 99 < h_angle < 156:
                
                             acceptor_list.append((n_donor_list[n], n_donor_list[n].get_parent().resname,n_donor_list[n].get_parent().id[1],
                                  i, i.get_parent().resname, i.get_parent().id[1], dist,
                                  i.serial_number, i.get_parent()['C'], i.get_parent()['C'].serial_number, h_angle))
                                              
    
for i in acceptor_list:
    print(i)
print('water', water)
```

keeping in mind https://proteopedia.org/wiki/index.php/Hydrogen_bonds fineprints
I get this kind of output for putative H bonds between mainchain O (from C=O) and N (putative donors)

```
.....
(<Atom N>, 'GLU', 403, <Atom O>, 'ALA', 400, 3.247074, 3024, <Atom C>, 3023, 106.052284)
(<Atom N>, 'LEU', 404, <Atom O>, 'SER', 401, 3.2268648, 3029, <Atom C>, 3028, 109.48323)
(<Atom N>, 'LEU', 404, <Atom O>, 'ALA', 400, 3.1475434, 3024, <Atom C>, 3023, 154.70815)
(<Atom N>, 'LEU', 405, <Atom O>, 'LEU', 402, 3.0635853, 3035, <Atom C>, 3034, 112.344406)
(<Atom N>, 'GLU', 406, <Atom O>, 'GLU', 403, 3.075921, 3043, <Atom C>, 3042, 105.97161)
(<Atom N>, 'GLY', 407, <Atom O>, 'LEU', 404, 2.9155347, 3052, <Atom C>, 3051, 115.01412)
(<Atom N>, 'LYS', 408, <Atom O>, 'GLU', 403, 3.044416, 3043, <Atom C>, 3042, 152.44513)
....
```